# Can't configure elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I enter the word "Booking" into the search, and already starting from the 5th result it returns "Cooking", but there are still results with the word "Booking", they contain it in the line.

```
$this->aQuery['query']['bool']['must'][]['multi_match'] = [
   'type' => 'cross_fields',
   'query' => 'Booking',
   'fields' => ['prod_name', 'prod_prefix'],
   'operator' => 'or'
];
```

I need results containing only the word "Booking". But if you enter "Travel Booking", then the results may contain both "Travel" and "Booking".

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the first part of the question, are you getting results that include the word Cooking but not the word Booking from that search?

Comment: The first 4 results contain "Booking". But in fact the results are much more

Comment: ["must"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["multi_match"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(12) "cross_fields"
            ["query"]=>
            string(7) "booking"
            ["fields"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              string(9) "prod_name"
              [1]=>
              string(11) "prod_prefix"
            }
            ["operator"]=>
            string(2) "or"
          }
        }
      }

Answer (score 0):

To get an exact match, use the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Match uses the, so called, analyzers to transform your search and find all matching words. Terms check for exact match on the search strings, so searching for Booking should not return documents that contain "Travel Booking".

As explained on the page:

> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields during analysis. For example, the default standard analyzer changes text field values as follows:
>
> - Removes most punctuation
> - Divides the remaining content into individual words, called tokens
> - Lowercases the tokens

> **The term query does not analyze the search term. The term query only searches for the exact term you provide. This means the term query may return poor or no results when searching text fields.**

Also note that you need to include a Keyword type in your index mappings

```
"prod_name": {
    "type":  "text",
    "fields": {
      "raw": { 
        "type":  "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
```

Then when you search for your word, you need to use the Keyword field name:

```
"term": {
  "prod_name.raw": {
    "value": "Booking",
    "boost": 1.0
  }
}
```